# Correct way to build multiple belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I've a rails table such as:

```
class CreateContent < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contents do |t|
      t.references :data_book,  null: false, index: true
      t.string :room_name,  null: false
      t.references :client,  null: false, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :contents, :data_books, on_delete: :cascade
    add_foreign_key :contents, :clients, on_delete: :cascade
  end
end
```

And my model specifies 2 `belongs_to` associations from `contents` to `data_books` and `clients`

I'm not sure what's the correct way to add new data instance for this; the official [Rails documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) specifies using `build_{association_name}` to do it but I can't do it since I've 2 different associations.

Is this the correct way to do it:

```
Content.new(
             data_book: DataBook.find(content_creation_params[:data_id]),
             room_name: @room_name,
             client: Client.find(content_creation_params[:client_id]),
)
```

Or is there a better, more rubyist way of doing this?

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong with what you're doing. If you were in the `ClientsController` you could do something like `@content_databook = DataBook.find(content_creation_params[:data_id]); @content = @client.build_content(room_name: @room_name, data_book: @content_databook)`.  You could do a similar thing if starting in `DataBooksController`. That's a standard pattern, but it depends on the full situation and what makes most sense.

Comment: I ended up creating it in the model as `def self.create!(data_book, client, room_name)
    @video_call = self.new({ room_name:  room_name, client: client})
    @video_call.data_book = data_book
    @video_call.save!
  end` Which is similar to your suggestion I think

Comment: FYI, you're table is being created incorrectly. `create_table :create_content` will create a table called "create_content". You need to do `create_table :contents` instead.

Comment: @jeffdill2 sorry that was an error while writing the question over here. I'll correct it in the question

Comment: @anonn023432 right on. :thumbsup:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you need any number of ways, all of which being valid.

```
# Option 1
Content.create(data_book: DataBook.create(whatever_params), client: Client.create(whatever_params))

# Option 2
data_book = DataBook.create(whatever_params)
client = Client.create(whatever_params)
content = Content.create(data_book: data_book, client: client)

# Option 3
content = Content.new
content.data_book = DataBook.find(id)
content.client = Client.find(id)
content.save

# Options 4
content = Content.new
data_book = content.build_data_book(whatever_params)
client = content.build_client(whatever_params)
content.save

# Etc. etc. etc.
...
```

Comment: I decided to follow option3 since that looked like the best way to me

Comment: Right on. And depending on the particular use-case, you'll likely do it all kinds of different ways as you build more stuff.